# Download file from server with ajax on firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

How can I Download file from a URL.

The code below works only on chrome:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '/xls',
                    data: {_csrf: this.csrf, hist:historicData },
                    method: 'POST',
                    // beforeSend: function(xhr){
                    //     xhr.setRequestHeader('historic', historicData);
                    // },
                    xhrFields: {
                        responseType: 'blob'
                    },                    
                    success: function (data) {
                        var a = document.createElement('a');
                        a.style = "display: none";  
                        var blob = new Blob(data, {type: "application/octet-stream"});
                        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        a.href = url;
                        a.download = filename;
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                        a.click();
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            document.body.removeChild(a);
                            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);  
                        }, 100);  

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                       alert(xhr.status);
                       alert(thrownError);
                   }
                });
```

On firefox nothing happing.

Firefox version : 63.0.3 (64-bit)

Chrome version: 70.0.3538.110

Network :

> Request URL: http://localhost:3000/xls Request method: POST Remote
>   address: [::1]:3000 Status code: 200 ok
>
> Preview: AAB4bC93b3JrYm9vay54bWxQSwECFAAKAAAAAAD.......
>
> esponse headers (519 B)    Cache-Control   no-cache, private, no-store,
>   m…=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Connection     keep-alive
>   Content-disposition    attachment; filename=xingamento Content-Type
>   application/vnd.ms-excel Date  Thu, 29 Nov 2018 23:38:17 GMT
>   Strict-Transport-Security  max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
>   Transfer-Encoding  chunked X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
>   X-DNS-Prefetch-Control     off X-Download-Options  noopen
>   X-Frame-Options    SAMEORIGIN X-XSS-Protection     1; mode=block

Comment: Something always happens. What do the dev tools say? Anything on the console (with full logging on)? Anything in the network tab? Does your code even trigger? How do you know it triggers?

Comment: What do the dev tools say : nothing.

Comment: network :Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
X-Download-Options: noopen
Preview: AAB4bC93b3JrYm9vay54bWxQSwECFAAKAAAAAAD.......

Comment: Don't add that as comment: [please put all the details in your question](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if I console  success: function (data)  returns me nothing

Comment: your success doesn't fire: where's your error handler? Without one, how would you even know an error occurred as far as `ajax()` can tell?

Comment: I also add a error handler and nothing

Comment: rather than `alert()`, use `console.log` so you don't block, and you don't force toString - add a console.log as first line in success, too, so you can see whether either, one, or neither fire at all. Because if neither run, but `$.ajax()` doesn't throw, then you should really start building a [mcve] because you might have a jquery bug, or you might not, and code reduction helps you find out which it is.